# How to decrease vertical space of the nomenclature title in a thesis

Tags: spacing

I am using TeXstudio in Windows 10  for my Ph.D. thesis.
I want to add nomenclature, so I add the following line in options --> Configure TeXstudio --> Makeindex

```
makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg
```

and the code in .cls file  in this link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/101GvLp6hknlY0TTdSl3r8ZkmH8IUm7de?usp=sharing

The vertical space of the nomenclature title in a thesis is very large, how to decrease it?

and This is a sample of the code in .cls  file

```
% Adjust spaces between header and the rest of pages for toc,lof,lot and nomenclature
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}{\vskip-10pt\@starttoc{toc}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\vskip-70pt\contentsname}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\@starttoc{lof}}{\vskip-10pt\@starttoc{lof}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\listfigurename}{\vskip-70pt\listfigurename}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\@starttoc{lot}}{\vskip-10pt\@starttoc{lot}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\listtablename}{\vskip-70pt\listtablename}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}{\chapter*{\nomname}}{\chapter*{\vskip-70pt\nomname\vskip-15pt}}{}{}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Definitions required for document formatting:
\linespread{1.5}
\setlength\parindent{40pt}
%\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}
\makenomenclature
\DeclareMathSizes{13}{14}{11}{9}


.
.
.
.
.
.


\mtcaddtoc{Acknowledgment}
\begin{MTCacknowledgement}
\begin{spacing}{1.4}  \input{acknowledgement}\end{spacing}   % include an acknowledgements.tex file          % By Desoky   as file name
\end{MTCacknowledgement} \newpage

\mtcaddtocNoTOC{Contents}
\tableofcontents            % generate and include a table of contents

\mtcaddtoc{List of Figures}
\listoffigures              % generate and include a list of figures

\mtcaddtoc{List of Tables}
\listoftables               % generate and include a list of tables

\mtcaddtoc{Nomenclature}
\printnomenclature[4cm]     % generate and include a list of abbreviations

\mtcaddtoc{Abstract}                                                                                                                      % By Desoky 
\begin{MTCabstract}
\begin{spacing}{1.4} \input{abstract}\end{spacing}          % include the abstract.tex
\end{MTCabstract} 


\end{romanpages}            % end roman page numbering
\end{spacing}
\mtcnorm}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information about your file by providing a MWE, a code that those who want to help you, can compile. There are related questions in the margins. Did you read any answers to them?

Comment: @C.Peters I have added the .cls file. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: The `nomencl` package by default invokes the `tocbasic` option and then it doesn't use the `\chapter` command in `\thenomenclature`, but the chapter heading is generated by `tocbasic`. So your patch is then ineffective. Use `\usepackage[notocbasic]{nomencl}` instead.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum  Wow. Thanks a lot, you saved my life. It is working.